# Where does Tomcat append / to directory paths?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6

Suppose my Tomcat webapps directory looks like this:

```
webapps/
webapps/fooapp/
webapps/fooapp/WEB-INF/
webapps/fooapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
webapps/fooapp/bardir/
```

When I make a GET request for `/fooapp/bardir`, Tomcat sees that webapps/fooapp/bardir is a directory and sends back a 302 to `/fooapp/bardir/` (with a slash at the end).

Here is my question: **Where *in the Tomcat source code* does this take place?**  (I'm looking at 6.0.x but a correct answer for any version would be a great starting point.)

The only reference material I can find on this subject is in the [Catalina Functional Specifications](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/funcspecs/fs-default.html) which states, regarding the Default Servlet:

> On each HTTP GET request processed by this servlet, the following processing shall be performed:
>
> [...]
>
> - If the requested resource is a directory:
>
>   - If the request path does not end with "/", redirect to a corresponding path with "/" appended so that relative references in welcome files are resolved correctly.

However, this functionality does not appear to be in org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet; or at least, it's not there exclusively: if I replace the default servlet in web.xml with a servlet whose *servlet-class does not exist*, directory paths *still come back 302* to add the slash, while every other request comes back with an error as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* it happens in [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper.Mapper](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_26/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/mapper/Mapper.java), namely in the `internalMapWrapper (Context, CharChunk, MappingData)` method.

But unfortunately I'm not really sure -- maybe this really is a question better suited for the [tomcat-users](http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-users) mailing list. Sorry for not having a better answer.

Comment: I think you found it!  And the 'default servlet' comment seems to show that someone was a bit confused on when servlet mapping ought to happen, exactly as I suspected.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 I asked the same question differently here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578548/lift-webapp-has-directory-and-resource-with-the-same-name-but-gives-302 thanks!

Comment: PS Jeppe from the Lift group posted this related bug (as yet unfixed): https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=32424

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse debugger learnt me that the redirect happens in line 504 of [`CoyoteAdapter`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/CoyoteAdapter.html) class, almost in the end of the [`postParseRequest()`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/CoyoteAdapter.html#postParseRequest%28org.apache.coyote.Request,%20org.apache.catalina.connector.Request,%20org.apache.coyote.Response,%20org.apache.catalina.connector.Response%29) method.

```
    // Possible redirect
    MessageBytes redirectPathMB = request.getMappingData().redirectPath;
    if (!redirectPathMB.isNull()) {
        // ...
        response.sendRedirect(redirectPath); // <--- Here.
        return false;
    }
```

Tomcat 6.0.20 btw.

**Update**: actually, the `redirectPath` is indeed filled by the `Mapper` as mentioned in @Henning's answer, indeed in the `internalMapWrapper()` method. Checkout the source code [here](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/mapper/Mapper.java.htm).

```
    if(mappingData.wrapper == null && noServletPath) {
        // The path is empty, redirect to "/"
        mappingData.redirectPath.setChars
            (path.getBuffer(), pathOffset, pathEnd);
        path.setEnd(pathEnd - 1);
        return;
    }
```