# cloudbees+lift application = broken navigation

Tags: scala, tomcat, web-applications, lift

I've been using Lift as the framework for a personal website, and in an effort to move the server off of my computer, I've turned to Cloudbees. I deployed my app to the cloud as a `.war` file and started browsing.

**edit** - Apparently this has nothing to do with Cloudbees. It's a Tomcat issue.

Locally, my app will serve `localhost:8008/demos` as the `demos.html` page. But on Cloudbees, `[URL]/demos` automatically redirects to `[URL]/demos/` and gives a 404. If I visit `[URL]/demos.html` directly, it seems to work fine.

I would like to avoid the explicit ".html" suffix on my pages. How can I get this to work so that things behave the way they do when I run locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've got this figured out, so I'm going to post my own answer for other peoples' future reference.

**The Problem**

Cloudbees uses Tomcat (not Jetty, which is what gets used with the sbt web plugin via `container:start`). As implied by [Where does Tomcat append / to directory paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815986/where-does-tomcat-append-to-directory-paths) Tomcat will append a `/` to paths that it thinks are directories.

With an app structure like

```
src/main/webapp
 - demos.html
 - demos
   - some-demo.html
```

And a lift sitemap definition that included

```
Menu.i("Demos") / "demos" submenus (
  Menu.i("Some Demo") / "demos" / "some-demo"
)
```

Tomcat was seeing the url "/demos" and seeing my "demos" folder, and assuming that my url was a mistake, adding the trailing slash.

**The Solution**

Work around the problem with a bit of rearrangement. First, move `demos.html` into the demos folder and rename it to `index.html`.

```
src/main/webapp
 - demos
   - index.html (formerly demos.html)
   - some-demo.html
```

Adjust the SiteMap to reflect this change

```
Menu.i("Demos") / "demos" / "index" submenus (...)
                            ^ added an extra path step
```

Now my auto-generated sitemap will point directly to `/demos/` and Tomcat happily serves my demos/index.html file in that place.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you have your Lift servlet mapped in `web.xml`? We use Tomcat with Lift on several applications and have not encountered this issue in a while. If I recall from reading the referenced thread, it had something to do with how it was mounted.

Comment: @jcern I'm at work now, so I can't tell you exactly, but if I recall correctly it's just whatever default web.xml came with the lift demo when I started the project. There's a LiftFilter and a filter-mapping that applies it to `/*`

Answer (score 0):

can you try running the war locally (in tomcat) and see if that happens? that doesn't seem to be anything specific to tomcat on cloudbees

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Tomcat (just sbt and `container:start` which I guess is a Jetty thing)... bear with me while I try to make this work.

Comment: Okay, it looks like I do get the same problem when I deploy my war to a local tomcat server.

Comment: yes, that is odd, lots do use tomcat. If you can create an app with an embedded jetty (ie a jar or zip) you can run that as is on CloudBees, if that helps.