# Where Tomcat 7 apply redirect 302 on directory (seo story))

Tags: tomcat, redirect, seo

As normal, tomcat 7 do a redirect 302 on a directory ressource if trailing slash is not present.

```
http://localhost/files --> 302, http://localhost/files/
```

We/I just want to change the response code to a permanetly redirection (301) in order to follown seo purpose. In my system, i cannot do this check before tomcat application...

I have made some test with tomcat7, and it seem that redirection occurs before a call to DefaultServlet.

I'm little in a trouble, if anyone have any idea, it will be very welcome

Jerome

Answer (score 0):

As answered in the comments to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815986/where-does-tomcat-append-to-directory-paths), the redirection happens in [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper.Mapper](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_42/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/mapper/Mapper.java). Look at the `internalMapWrapper` method.